# Slack API - Attatchments from custom bot post as plain text

Tags: python, slack-api, slack

I'm using Python 2.7 along with a [python-slackclient](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient). I have an attachment structure like so:

```
self.msg = {
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "%s, %s" % (self.jiraIssueObj.fields.summary, self.link),
            "pretext": "Detail summary for %s" % self.jiraIssueObj,
            "title": self.jiraIssueObj.fields.summary,
            "title_link": self.link,
            "text": self.jiraIssueObj.fields.description[0:self.maxSummary],
            "color": "#7CD197",
            "mrkdwn_in": ["text", "pretext", "fields"]
        }
    ]
}
```

then,

```
def Send(self):
        if (self.msg):
            slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=self.channel, text=self.msg, as_user=True)
            self.msg = None
```

However, when this posts, it just posts the plaintext, with no formatting:

> {"attachments": [{"title": "Upgrade Grafana to 3.0", "color": "#7CD197
> ", "text": "I\u2019ve added the JIRA maillist so this email
> will create a ticket we can queue it up in support.\u00a0 Eric if you
> wouldn\u2019t mind just replying to this email with the additional
> info?\n\n\u00a0\n\n\u00a0\n\nSent: Thursday, August
> 25, 2016 11:41 AM\n", "title_link":
> "https://jira.jr.com/browse/ops-164", "mrkdwn_in": ["text",
> "pretext", "fields"], "pretext": "Detail summary for ops-164",
> "fallback": "Upgrade Grafana to 3.0,
> https://jira.jr.com/browse/ops-164"}]}

What am I doing wrong? I've tried also doing `attachments=self.msg` in the `Send()` call, but I get no output at all to my slack channel when doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out, the call to

```
slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=self.channel, attachments=self.msg, as_user=True)
```

apears to add the top layer `{ "attachments": ... }` for you. So by changing my `self.msg` to simply be:

```
self.format = [{
    "fallback": "%s, %s" % (self.jiraIssueObj.fields.summary, self.link),
    "pretext": "Detail summary for %s" % self.jiraIssueObj,
    "title": self.jiraIssueObj.fields.summary,
    "title_link": self.link,
    "text": self.jiraIssueObj.fields.description[0:self.maxSummary],
    #"color": "#7CD197",
    "mrkdwn_in": ["text", "pretext", "fields"]
}]
```

without this outer `{ "attachments": ... }` wrapper, the api was able to post the message attachment as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The chat.postMessage method has a couple of quirks -- like most of Slack's web APIs, it only supports `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-types, and does not support JSON. The quirkier aspect is that the `attachments` parameter takes a URL-encoded array of JSON. Right now, it appears you're sending the `text` parameter a native Python array.

For Slack to understand that structure, you'll first need to turn it into a JSON string. The API wrapper you're using can probably handle the next step of conversion into a URL-encoded representation.

Finally, the attachment itself doesn't get placed in the `text` of the message -- that's a separate field. You'll want to specify something more like this, after defining your JSON string as `self.attachments`:

`slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel=self.channel, attachments=self.attachments, as_user=True)`

The `text` field becomes optional once you include attachments.

Comment: I tried doing `attachments=json.dumps(self.msg)`, and while this produced a JSON string (https://gist.github.com/calebtote/80a3803a717b1d908fc48986d8e876e3) it still doesn't actually post to the channel anything.